# _CrtSetDbgFlag not working as expected: returns NULL

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17, crtdbg.h

I have added below lines of code in application :

#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include 
#include <crtdbg.h>
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define DEBUG_NEW new(_NORMAL_BLOCK, **FILE**, **LINE**)
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif

and

```
HANDLE hLogFile;
hLogFile = CreateFileA("c:\\memoryLeaksDump.txt", GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

_CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE);
_CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE);
_CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE);
_CrtSetReportFile(_CRT_WARN, hLogFile);
_CrtSetReportFile(_CRT_ERROR, hLogFile);
_CrtSetReportFile(_CRT_ASSERT, hLogFile);

_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
```

i don't see any memory leaks detected in the output file. I see below lines printed:

(null)(-1) : atlTraceGeneral - Error 1 in XML File

Can someone me out in resolving the issue and help me in getting the memory leaks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: _CrtSetDbgFlag returns previous value of flag, more of it is not called if _DEBUG not defined. Not clear what you actually expect

Comment: When i am running the application, i don't see any memory leaks reported with code implemented, (null)(-1) : atlTraceGeneral - Error 1 in XML File is written in the memory leaks file or the output window